# code works perfectly in server one but not in server 2

Tags: php, android

I am posting certain values from front end (android) to back end (php) and this webservice code works well in server one, but for some unknown reason its not working in server 2.

What I found is `mysql_query` is not working and data is not inputing to the table.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_booking(booking_name,booking_address,booking_date,booking_phno,description)
```

Here is the full code

```
<?php

$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost","touchlive","touchlive");

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("raora", $con);
$response ="FALSE";
$booking_name = $_POST['name'];
$booking_address =$_POST['address'];
$booking_date = $_POST['date'];
$booking_phno =$_POST['phno'];
$description =$_POST['description'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_booking(booking_name,booking_address,booking_date,booking_phno,description) 

VALUES ('$booking_name','$booking_address','$booking_date', '$booking_phno', '$description')");

if(result ==0) 
$response ="TRUE";

echo $response;

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You do no form of validation or error-handling, you just assume that everything will work out. Start off with [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) and [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: You really should check the manual, the `mysql_*` functions have been removed from php 7. You should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements to get rid of the sql injection problem you have now.

Comment: And what is `if(result ==0) `?

Comment: Virtually everything you're doing here is wrong.  I know that doesn't help, but just saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
 your code has
 if(result == 0)

 where is ' $ '
 if($result == 0) like this

 and give ur db connection like this

$host="your host";
$port=1234;
$socket="/tmp/mysql.sock";
$user="root";
$password="123456789";
$dbname="dbname";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);

change all above variables as per your details
socket can be empty .
```

Comment: There's a bit more to it than just that: The syntax is different (the db connection is required) and not all `mysql_*` functions have made it to `msyqli_*`.

Comment: your code has
 if(result == 0)

 where is ' $ '
 if($result == 0) like this